# Firebase deploy hosting. Others can see the changes but I can't

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-hosting

After I build my Angular 5 app and then run

```
firebase deploy --only hosting
```

... other people (not within network) can see the proper changes and I am the only one who can't see them.

I am the only developer. I cleared cache on Chrome, opened in private mode, used another browser (Firefox), and nothing.

I can see the changes when I use a VPN. Is this problem related to my IP address? Why does it happen?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you are hitting a node on the CDN that accidentally wasn't clear when you deployed the latest update. This should be really rare.

The simplest fix is to deploy the update again, which will force another purge of all CDN edges. If that doesn't fix it, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting

Comment: Must have been that. I could see the changes normally after several hours